# HHVM The 'parse' command line option is not supported

Tags: php, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, hhvm

I think that the title is clear.

I've installed the facebook hhvm with the objective to obtain the AST of php source code.

However when I call the vm with the parse option the result is:

"HHVM The 'parse' command line option is not supported"

The system on which I'm using the hhvm is the last Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: Please I can't find nothing on the web! No documentation, no examples! Please!

Comment: Is it possible that no one has some information about this problem!?
I can't believe it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't supported in HHVM: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/blob/c494c3a145008f65d349611eb2d09d0c33f1ab23/hphp/runtime/base/program_functions.cpp#L1111 .

It was used for the old PHP to C++ compiler. If you really need it, open a task on github but it won't be very high priority for us as we are working hard on Zend parity right now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention I really appreciate it! :)
I think that at this point I'll try to implement the type inference by myself as I really need it to accomplish my goals.